# Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'isInitialRoute'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the below library:

https://pub.dev/packages/animated_background

called `animated_background`

when I am trying to run the code, I found the below error:

```
Compiler message:
lib/helpers/fade_route.dart:12:18: Error: The getter 'isInitialRoute' isn't defined for the class 'RouteSettings'.
 - 'RouteSettings' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart' ('/D:/programs/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'isInitialRoute'.
    if (settings.isInitialRoute)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

as this is the below figure which contains the error:

[image: error]

and this is the related code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FadeRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  FadeRoute({ WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings })
      : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      Widget child) {
    if (settings.isInitialRoute)
      return child;
    return new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
  }
}

class SimpleFadeRoute<T> extends FadeRoute<T> {
  SimpleFadeRoute({ Widget child, RouteSettings settings })
      : super(builder: (_) => child, settings: settings);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That property [was removed from RouteSettings](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/51435). See the following [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/route-navigator-refactoring) for an alternative.

> We removed the isInitialRoute property from RouteSetting as part of
> refactoring, and provided the onGenerateInitialRoutes API for full
> control of initial routes generation.
>
> There are different ways to migrate this change. One way is to set the
> initial route name to a fixed value and generate a specific route
> (FakeSplashRoute in the above example) for the route name.

```
MaterialApp(
  initialRouteName: ‘fakeSplash’,
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSetting setting) {
    if (setting.name == ‘fakeSplash’)
      return FakeSplashRoute();
    else
      return RealRoute(setting);
  }
)
```

> If there is a more complicated use case, you can use the new API,
> onGenerateInitialRoutes, in MaterialApp or CupertinoApp.

```
MaterialApp(
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSetting setting) {
    return RealRoute(setting);
  },
  onGenerateInitialRoutes: (String initialRouteName) {
    return <Route>[FakeSplashRoute()];
  }
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and your interests, So how can I implement this to the posted code in my question :D

Comment: Can't you use the suggestion in the migration guide?

Comment: I am trying to understand the guide, but it's so complicated for me :(, but let me try to concentrate and follow the guide may be I can reach the full answer, thank you very much for your suggestion :)..... I am gonna accept your answer soon :).....